# Multiple verbs in one sentence using ことがある

Tags: grammar

I'm studying for an upcoming exam, and in our study guide for the essay section there is a prompt to write about "I have the experience of ....ing, .....ing, and so forth." We're supposed to use ことがある, but I'm unsure how to list multiple verbs using this form. We're also learning たり and や as well. (This is for Lesson 11 from Genki I)

The "...ing" makes me think it is something like 旅{りょ}行{こう}するの、泳{およ}ぐの、散{さん}歩{ぽ}することがあります。

Is this close at all?

Comment: But I guess you should use たり or や?

Comment: I'm guessing you can combine たり and 〜てあります: 旅行したり、泳いだり、散歩したりしたことがあります

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your textbook probably explains, you have to use the ta-form, not the nominalizer-の. A ta-form can directly modify こと as a relative clause. If you want to list two verbs, you can 1) use ～たり/だり～する, or 2) use two or more こと's and join them with や.

> - 犬を飼ったことがあります。
> - この池で泳いだり魚を釣ったりしたことがあります。
> - 小説を書いたことやそれを出版したことがあります。

Note that the verb must be in the ta-form. 泳ぐことがあります would mean "I sometimes/occasionally swim".

If you're trying to make a formal sentence (like in a job interview), a more direct and preferred translation of "I have experience of ～" is ～(の)経験があります. Then you can also use any noun-based expression (incl. suru-verb) as well as the ta-form of a verb.

> - JavaScriptやPythonなどの経験があります。
> - JavaScriptでの開発の経験があります。
> - JavaScriptで開発した経験があります。